# Android Service is Called before Activity

Tags: android

I am making a service periodically sending location to the server. But when my application started service started while I am not calling service in my Main Activity. The service is automatically called.
Thanks in advance...

my java code

```
    setContentView(R.layout.sliding);

    startService(new Intent(getBaseContext(), response.class));
      Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.add(Calendar.SECOND, 40);

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, response.class);

        // Add extras to the bundle
        intent.putExtra("foo", "bar");
        // Start the service
       // startService(intent);


        PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, intent, 0);

        AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        int i;
        i=15;
        alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(),
                i* 1000, pintent);


        startService(intent);
```

My Manifest File

  `

```
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>


    <activity android:name="com.siliconicpro.sayminicab.Register"
       android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
       android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"/>
    <activity android:name="com.siliconicpro.sayminicab.Login"
       android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
       android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"/>
    <activity android:name="com.siliconicpro.sayminicab.sliding"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
         android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
       android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
       />
    <service android:name="services.response"
        ></service>
     <service android:name="services.CallService"
        ></service>
```

and my service code is following

```
public class response extends Service {
private static String KEY_SUCCESS = "success";
private static String KEY_ERROR = "error";
private String email1;
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO: Return the communication channel to the service.
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Service Created", 1).show();
    super.onCreate();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Service Destroy", 1).show();
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
//  

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "service running", 1).show();
```

}
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);

```
        }
```

Comment: That's my calling code

Comment: Can u post java files with AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: Pratik Butani my code is given above

Comment: @ツPratikButaniツ now manifest and code is given

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
startService(new Intent(getBaseContext(), response.class));
```

this is the culprit, remove it and then try.

Comment: @ Anuj Sharma  it's not working.
I am Toasting to check it but as my application run service onstartcommand() method called, and my oncreate() method is called on button clicked.

Comment: service is also not stopped on stopService(new Intent(myclass.this,CallService.class));